# Input at bottom is pushed more than needed in ios when keyboard opens

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

Basically, I have this html:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body style='background:red;margin:0;'>
    <div style='background:white;height:100%;position:absolute;width:100%;'>
        <input type='text' value='click me' style='bottom:0;position:absolute;'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(not my actual code, but simplified enough to reproduce the issue).

And, whenever I place the focus in safari for ios, the soft keyboard is open and the input is pushed up some extra pixels leaving an empty spot under it with the color of the body. I tried a lot of css properties and played with scroll of elements in js but couldn't get the view to not be scrolled that far.

[image: current behaviour]

Do you have any idea of what can I do to fix that? (other than ignore the issue or change the placement of the input, since both are requested to be like that in the proyect)

This is what I'm trying to get:

[image: expected]

Thanks

Comment: Wow a big problem. cant figure it out. you want an address bar coloring?

Comment: @ZeevKatz Uhm. no, I want the space between the keyboard and the input (red part in first screenshot) to disapear.

Comment: i get it, but why you need red background? for address bar color?

Comment: @ZeevKatz Nono, it was for demostrative purposes, so it's easy to see what's happening. If I used white, it would be harder to notice the space. Actually, in the project it is black.

Comment: I have the same issue as well. Did you manage to solve it?